# How to kill Thread + .net + System.AddIn

Tags: .net, multithreading, system.addin

I have developed one scheduler which is creating new thread at each new event. In that thread based on some id one dll is loaded using System.AddIn.

Now i want to kill that event in a midway?

How can i implement this functionality in this situation

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are loading the addins in a separate appdomain. If not, start doing it. 
Otherwise you can't kill them in a controlled manner.

To kill an addin, unload the appdomain.